# How to wire an outside switch with separate load compression glands

Tags: power-supply, switches

I have a remote control outside switch (Knightsbridge IP663G) which splits a mains line into three, its taking a uk mains cable through the left and I want to connect another mains cable (for lights outside) through one of its three outputs. The confusing thing is it has different load compression glands. One is rated 8A and the other two 2.5. Aren't plugs rated for 13 Amps here in the UK? Why is this being lowered through the switch? Is it ok to wire an outside plug to the 8A gland?